# Laravel 4.2 doesn't work on public server

Tags: php, laravel, ftp, laravel-4

I installed laravel 4.2 and in my wamp server everything goes right.

But when I copied all project to my FTP server, I get white screen window with no errors. Just white screen.

The only thing that I have done was to remove the public folder from the URL via this url -> http://creolab.hr/2013/03/removing-the-public-segment-in-a-laravel-4-app/

I did that on Laravel 4.0 and when I copied everything works fine, but with this 4.2 its diferent.

Any help?

Comment: Check your server logs to see what is the error...

Comment: Have you made the `app/storage` directory writable? It's very likely that logs can't be written because of lacking permissions.

Comment: Yes I did :/ its only in Laravel 4.2 :/

Comment: check the logs ... usually whitescreen is permissions on storage folder ... also you could set debug to true atm so you can find any errors

Comment: I had a similar problem and the logs were empty - in my case it was fault of PHP 5.2 enabled by default by the hosting provider. Laravel requires PHP 5.3, it uses `__DIR__` variable in index.php so it can't initialize the logger if it's PHP<5.3.

And you probably can't see the error message because of display_errors (you can try: `ini_set('display_errors', 1)`).

Comment: Laravel 4.2 requires PHP 5.4